# prevent users from adding content to rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

When you make a site in rails, it creates some pages automatically that allow you to add conctent to your site. You usually acces them by typing domain.com/something/new in the browser.

Let's say you want to upload the site to the internet. How can you prevent users from accesing that pages? Deleting them doesn't seem like a good method because then how can you add conctent to the site? Do you password protect them? Is there some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to authenticate the user and call authenticate_user in the controller to ensure only authenticated users can go to that page. You can also take a look at [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) which gives you more control like setting read, write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly a hundred ways to do this. It depends on what you need and what you want. 
If you don't want people to post stuff on your site and you don't need to do that yourself, why don't you just delete routing to `/yourmodel/new` from `/app/controllers/yourmodel_controller.rb`, `/app/views/yourmodel/new.html.erb` and the entry from `/config/routes.rb`?

Furthermore, you can use some gem for authentication. There are several. Have a look at [clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance). It'll let you make some pages accessible for registered users only. If you want to hide a few pages from - let's say - common users so that only admins can access them, have a look at [aegis](https://github.com/makandra/aegis).